# How do i add data in two different collections using firestore and flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So i have a collection users and a sub-collection in users which is cart, so what i want to achive is to be able to add a counter to the amount of items i have added in users collections and also the sum of the price, and in the subcollection cart i want to add the necessary data for example item id and store id and the amount of each item. The way i implemented is prob very wrong but it work as in now however! When i spam the buttons the amount is not correct in user collection. I tried using a timer so that you can update or set a document every 1 second, but it makes the whole user experience feel slow and odd

```
        !snapshot1.hasData || snapshot1.data!.docs.isEmpty
    ? InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
            await cartupdate.doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('docId')).set({
              'docId': snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('docId'),
              'productAmount': 1,
              'userId': "WEhxbwBPeI1HIZvIStkM",
              'cartTime': DateTime.now(),
            }).then((value) {
              print("product cart added and useramount + 1");
              users.doc(snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('uid')).update({
                'usercartAmount': snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('usercartAmount') + 1,
                'usercheckoutAmount': snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('usercheckoutAmount') + snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('productPrice')
              });
            }).catchError((error) {
              print("Failed to add service: $error");
            });
          });
        },
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 35,
        ))))
    : InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
            await cartupdate.doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('docId')).update({
              'productAmount': snapshot1.data!.docs[0].get('productAmount') + 1,
            }).then((value) async {
              print("product amount +1");
              await users.doc(snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('uid')).update({
                'usercartAmount': snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('usercartAmount') + 1,
                'usercheckoutAmount': snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('usercheckoutAmount') + snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('productPrice')
              });
            }).catchError((error) {
              print("Failed to add service: $error");
            });
          });
        },
        child: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 35,
        ))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the way you are incrementing your data. Instead of

```
users.doc(snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('uid')).update({
  'usercartAmount': snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('usercartAmount') + 1,
  'usercheckoutAmount': snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('usercheckoutAmount') +
      snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('productPrice')
});
```

try this:

```
users.doc(snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('uid')).update({
  'usercartAmount': FieldValue.increment(1),
  'usercheckoutAmount':
      FieldValue.increment(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('productPrice'))
});
```

[FieldValue.increment](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) increases the value based on its current value.

If the currentValue is 12, `FieldValue.increment(5);FieldValue.increment(5);` updates the value to `22` (i.e 12 + 5 + 5). Your method could update the value to 17 (if both calls have a currentValue of 12).

With this, you can rewrite your first `ontap` function like this:

```
onTap: () {
  // no need for timer (delay), since the update function is updated
  // based on its current value.
  await cartupdate.doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('docId')).set({
    'docId': snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('docId'),
    'productAmount': 1,
    'userId': "WEhxbwBPeI1HIZvIStkM",
    'cartTime': DateTime.now(),
  });
  await users.doc(snapshot3.data!.docs[0].get('uid')).update({
    'usercartAmount': FieldValue.increment(1),
    'usercheckoutAmount':
        FieldValue.increment(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('productPrice'))
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you king!

Comment: So glad I could help.